# Cant get Exception object on default error.html Thymeleaf page

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a Spring Boot application and want to display the exception on the error page.

I put the error.html page in the template directory and I can see the change, but the *exception* variable keeps coming back as null. I can see all the other data like message and stacktrace.

I took this from several examples.  What is missing?

Thymeleaf

```
   <div class="row rowDesign">
      <div class="col-md-4 ml-auto">
        <span class="legend">Date</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <span th:text="${timestamp}"></span>
      </div>
    </div>    
    <div class="row rowDesign">
      <div class="col-md-4 ml-auto">
        <span class="legend">Error</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <span th:text="${error}"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row rowDesign">
      <div class="col-md-4 ml-auto">
        <span class="legend">Status</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <span th:text="${status}"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row rowDesign">
      <div class="col-md-4 ml-auto">
        <span class="legend">Message</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <span th:text="${message}"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row rowDesign">
      <div class="col-md-4 ml-auto">
        <span class="legend">Exception</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <span th:text="${exception}"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row rowDesign">
      <div class="col-md-4 ml-auto">
        <span class="legend">Trace</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <span th:text="${trace}"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your `application.properties`:

```
server.error.include-exception=true
server.error.include-stacktrace=always
```

These properties are not enabled by default (See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html)